# How does gcc push local variables on to the stack?

Tags: variables, gcc, stack, allocation

```
void
f
    ()
{
    int a[1];
    int b;
    int c;
    int d[1];
}
```

I have found that these local variables, for this example, are not pushed on to the stack in order. b and c are pushed in the order of their declaration, but, a and d are grouped together. So the compiler is allocating arrays differently from any other built in type or object.

Is this a C/C++ requirement or gcc implementation detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard says nothing about the order in which local variables are allocated. It doesn't even use the word "stack". It only requires that local variables have a *lifetime* that begins on entry to the nearest enclosing block (basically when execution reaches the `{`) and ends on exit from that block (reaching the `}`), and that each object has a unique address. It does acknowledge that two unrelated variables might happen to be adjacent in memory (for obscure technical reasons involving pointer arithmetic), but doesn't say when this might happen.

The order in which variables are allocated is entirely up to the whim of the compiler, and you should not write code that depends on any particular ordering. A compiler might lay out local variables in the order in which they're declared, or alphabetically by name, or it might group some variables together if that happens to result in faster code.

If you need to variables to be allocated in a particular order, you can wrap them in an array or a structure.

(If you were to look at the generated machine code, you'd most likely find that the variables are not "pushed onto the stack" one by one. Instead, the compiler will probably generate a single instruction to adjust the stack pointer by a certain number of bytes, effectively allocating a single chunk of memory to hold *all* the local variables for the function or block. Code that accesses a given variable will then use its offset within the stack frame.)

And since your function doesn't do anything with its local variables, the compiler might just not bother allocating space for them at all, particularly if you request optimization with `-O3` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can order the local variables however it wants. It may even choose to either not allocate them at all (for example, if they're not used, or are optimized away through propagation/ciscizing/keeping in register/etc) or allocate the same stack location for multiple locals that have disjoint live ranges.

There is no common implementation detail to outline how a particular compiler does it, as it may change at any time.

Typically, compilers will try to group similar sized variables (and/or alignments) together to minimize wasted space through "gaps", but there are so many other factors involved.

structs and arrays have slightly different requirements, but that's beyond the scope of this question I believe.