# defining a variable and use right away

Tags: c++

What's the difference between defining a variable and use right away, versus use later? Do they also land in different section of memory map due to initialization?

For example:

1. defined and used right away

```cpp
    int a = b+2;
```

2. defined and used later

```cpp
    int a;
    a=b+2;
```

Comment: I assume it's a local variable (second example wouldn't compile otherwise). If by "sections of memory map" you mean data sections of the compiled binary, then local variables generally don't appear there at all.

Comment: It may not be in memory at all.  It may be in a register.  Or it may be optimized out entirely.  All that you know in C++ is that a local variable will have *automatic* storage, and if optimized out it will behave *as-if* it was still present.  You can read more on [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/book/storage_durations) here.

Comment: Side note: when there are no differences in observable behaviour, no changes that the user can possibly see, the compiler can do whatever it wants, turning one 1 into 2 or 2 onto 1 or even discarding the computations entirely. This is called the [As-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). This is what allows compilers to optimize code. It is best to think of your code as describing behaviour to the compiler, not as instructions to be executed. The compiler's job is to generate the instructions that will perform the described behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For [primitive types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) like `int`, there is no difference here. The two snippets will create the exact same behavior.

However, this changes when you're dealing with class objects. There can be a big difference between:

```
foo obj = b + 2;
```

And

```
foo obj;
obj = b + 2;
```

If `b` is of type `int` and `foo` is defined as:

```
class foo {
private:
    int a;
public:
    foo(int x) : a(x) { }
};
```

Then the second snippet (`foo obj; obj = b + 2`) won't even compile, while the first still will.

Here's an example with some prints that you can run and debug through to see what's happening: https://ideone.com/QE5WlK

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
private:
    int a;
public:
    foo() : a(0) { std::cout << "Default Ctor" << std::endl; }
    foo(int x) : a(x) { std::cout << "Int Ctor" << std::endl; }
    foo& operator=(int x) {
        std::cout << "Int Assignment Op" << std::endl;
        a = x;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    int b = 5;
    
    foo obj = b + 2;
    foo obj2; obj2 = b + 2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though initialisation and assignment are not the same thing, in this particular example the two snippets of code have absolutely the same semantics, so you have created the same program in different ways.

There will be zero difference in the behaviour or implementation of these programs.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to local variables, in which case the two examples would not be very different. Just that example two uses up two statements to do the same thing. Local variables use the stack pointer, so if you want to know more about how that works see here [How does gcc push local variables on to the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025216/how-does-gcc-push-local-variables-on-to-the-stack)

If these were global variables, example 1 would probably initialize the variables in `section .data` straight away and example 2 would reserve the amount of bytes of `sizeof(int)` in `section .bss` and then assign the values in the code section.