# How will the local variables and arrays stored in stack?

Tags: arrays, c, stack

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfU6n.png[**][1]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWVLf.png%27)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 23;
    int y = 24;
    int z = 25;
    int asar= 26;
    int a[5];    
    int p = 15;
    int q = 16;
    int r = 17;
    a[11]=56;
    a[10]=57;
    a[9]=58;
    a[8]=59;
    a[7]=60;
    a[6]=61;
    a[5]=62;
  
    printf("\t x=%d, y=%d, z=%d,asar=%d, p=%d, q=%d, r=%d \n", x, y, z, asar, p, q, r);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to cross the bound of array and which causes undefined behavior but here I found that all the values out of the bound of array are copied in a sequence that
value of highest index 
**11** got copied in `x`(first declaration)
**10** got copied in `y`(second declaration)
**9** got copied in `z`(third declaration)
**8** got copied in `asar`(fourth declaration)
**7** got copied in `p`(fifth declaration)
**6** got copied in `q`(sixth declaration)
**5** got copied in `r`(seventh declaration)

There are altogether 7 other variables other than `a` and I have crossed limit of `a` exactly by **7** as such (4+7=11) and I got the output as:
**x=56, y=57, z=58,asar=59, p=60, q=61, r=62** 
 is there any logic behind this or?

Don't be amazed why I considered the memory allocation in stack because there are **7** variables excluding `a` and exceeded **7** values are copied one after the other. At least it is true in every case for me when number of extra variables is equal to bound exceed.

 Is there any logical explanation regarding this or the question is worthless?

Comment: Basically the standard does not mandate to use a stack or anything else how to store local variables. The compiler is free to use any ordering for your variables. Don't expect anything specific. ... and don't be surprised if undefined behaviour looks strange in the end.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025216/how-does-gcc-push-local-variables-on-to-the-stack

Comment: If you need a certain sequence of your variables, use a `struct`. Otherwise, you should not care.

Comment: @paddy: There is nothing wrong with asking about the things that happen in undefined behavior. First, the term “undefined behavior” as used in the C standard means only that the C standard does not define the behavior; it does not mean that nothing else defines the behavior. (The C standard in fact defines only a core programming language that is intended to be extended by implementations adding their own definitions to extend the language.) Second, when one does go beyond the defined behavior, the universe does not simply go haywire and abandon all reason…

Comment: … There are still explanations of what does happen, things that occur as consequences of how we design compilers, how we design computers, how we guard against malicious actors, and more. When an engineer designs a building or machine and defines how it ought to be used normally, it is still hugely useful for other engineers to study what happens when something goes wrong. It is useful to study what happens when a building’s foundation is eroded so future buildings can be designed to withstand that better or to fail in a better way than in the past…

Comment: … Similarly, it is useful to understand how programs are implemented behind the facade of the programming language, to understand the mechanics behind it, for several reasons. Using that knowledge to design programs to be better able to resist attackers is one. Being familiar with the common ways in which bugs cause programs to fail is another, because it improves a person’s ability to diagnose bugs. Learning about so-called “undefined behavior” is immensely valuable and reasonable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil fair call, thanks for calling me out out my attitude. :)

Answer (score 1):

While `auto` variables are almost always stored on a stack, this isn't enforced by the C standard.

> For such an object *[with automatic storage duration]* that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end, execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.
>
> [6.2.4 Storage durations of objects, C11]

The data structure which best fit the description is indeed a stack but it is not defined in the standard, and there are no specific order to store the variables. CPU usually require data to be aligned a certain way to access them quickly, and the compiler may (and will) reorder them to reduce unused addresses. Adding a `char` somewhere in the code may change the internal order of the variables.

Moreover, trying to access objects from other objects addresses is undefined behaviour. Even if you get "lucky" and get it to work the way you want, it may break later for some seemingly unrelated reasons. For example, by changing the optimization level, the compiler may delete or merge certain variables, or place them in registers that you cannot access. Exploiting undefined behaviour is never a good idea.

If you need to ensure a specific order for your data, you can use a `struct`, whose order is guaranteed.

> As discussed in 6.2.5, a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, **whose storage is allocated in an ordered sequence**, and a union is a type consisting of a sequence of members whose storage overlap.
>
> [6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers, C99]

Accessing members through the `struct` object pointer is valid, but the compiler can insert padding in-between members. The `offsetof()` macro is necessary to correctly access them. (Related : http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)